# Verify that Nginx is serving static files instead of Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app running `gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 flaskapp:app` with below nginx config. However, how can I tell if nginx is actually serving the static files or not? I tried changing the `alias  /home/pi/Public/flaskapp/static/;` to `.../static-testing/;` and just put a placeholder `style.css` there but the page seems to load like before.

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/pi/Public/flaskapp/static/;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? does one have to specify something in the routes of flask?

Comment: Just stop flask and try to load static file

Comment: stopping gunicorn flask will not load anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally configured the nginx properly. I added root and removed hard path of static, also added log-files that clearly shows that static and css is being loaded from nginx! I also changed the listening port to be 80 (suprise).

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name myapp.com;
    root /home/pi/Public/myapp;

    access_log /home/pi/Public/myapp/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/pi/Public/myapp/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static/ { }

    location /uploads/ { }
}
```

Comment: can you add caching too ?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably test this with empty path mentioned in the /static/ location.

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name _;

    location /static/ {

    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

}

This will give 404 error and thus you can verify if files are served by Nginx.

Comment: still loads files in static folder. conclusion: my setup is not working properly?

Comment: Can you try putting `/static` block above `/` block then see if this works ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to log some upstream variables into the access log.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables

You should add this into your nginx conf in the http block

```
upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

Then change the proxy_pass to http://backend;

Now add

```
log_format upstream '$upstream_bytes_received $upstream_response_time';
access_log /var/log/nginx-upstream upstream;
```

to your server block and restart nginx.
you will see '-' when nginx does not request the upstream.

Doc: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html & http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom header to your nginx location block and see if it's set on your static files.

Comment: how do I do that? I am new using nginx.